# JSON Formatting Issues in Python from Walmart JSON Open API Feed

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am having some issues getting the python JSON module to parse some JSON information generated by the walmart Open API.

I can retreive the JSON file from the url of the item as string and it looks like this:

I have this information in a pandas module such that each element in the table looks like this:

```
print(raw_json[0])
b'{
   "itemId":43090845,
   "parentItemId":43090845,
   "name":"Better Homes and Gardens Owl Memory Foam Bath Rug, 20\\"   x     30\\"",
   "msrp":15.88,
   "salePrice":14.88,
   "upc":"040773068722",
   "categoryPath":"Home/Bath/Bath Rugs & Mats",
   "shortDescription":"Pamper your feet with this Memory Foam bath mat     from Mohawk Home. All synthetic textiles enable it to stand up to moisture.     Slip-resistant backing makes it extra safe and fast drying. Bath rug is     machine washable.",
   "longDescription":"&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Better Homes and Gardens Owl     Memory Foam Bath Rug, 20&quot; x     30&quot;:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Machine     washable&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Slip-resistant backing&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Fast     drying&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Soft to touch&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Material     Content: Polyester&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Better Homes and Garden bath rugs is     extra safe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;",
   "brandName":"Better Homes & Gardens",
   "thumbnailImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
   "mediumImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
   "largeImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
   "productTrackingUrl":"http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-    bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&    tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.walmart.com%252Fip%252FBetter-    Homes-and-Gardens-Owl-Memory-Foam-Bath-Rug-20-    x-30%252F43090845%253Faffp1%253D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
   "ninetySevenCentShipping":false,
   "standardShipRate":5.99,
   "size":"20\\"   x 30\\"",
   "color":"Brown",
   "marketplace":false,
   "shipToStore":true,
   "freeShipToStore":true,
   "modelNumber":"BH15-005-599-01",
   "productUrl":"http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=https%3A%2F    %2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FBetter-Homes-and-Gardens-Owl-Memory-Foam-Bath-    Rug-20-x-30%2F43090845%3Faffp1%3D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlya    pi",
   "customerRating":"4.4",
   "numReviews":5,
   "customerRatingImage":"http://i2.walmartimages.com/i/CustRating    /4_4.gif",
   "categoryNode":"4044_539095_920259",
   "rhid":"30609",
   "bundle":false,
   "clearance":false,
   "preOrder":false,
   "stock":"NOT_AVAILABLE",
   "attributes":{
      "color":"Brown",
      "ironBankCategory":"Home Decor",
      "size":"20\\"      x 30\\""
   },
   "gender":"Unisex",
   "addToCartUrl":"http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=http%3A%2F    %2Faffil.walmart.com%2Fcart%2FaddToCart%3Fitems%3D43090845%7C1%26affp1%3D3NMs    qL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlya    pi",
   "affiliateAddToCartUrl":"http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-    bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&    tmpid=1082&    RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Faffil.walmart.com%252Fcart%252FaddToCart%253Fitem    s%253D43090845%257C1%2526affp1%253D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
   "freeShippingOver35Dollars":true,
   "imageEntities":[
      {
         "thumbnailImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "mediumImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "largeImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "entityType":"SECONDARY"
      },
      {
         "thumbnailImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "mediumImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "largeImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "entityType":"SECONDARY"
      },
      {
         "thumbnailImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/56639088-94cb-46b3-8a3c-    750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=100&        odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "mediumImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "largeImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "entityType":"PRIMARY"
      }
   ],
   "availableOnline":false
}'
```

-> I have done nothing to change the output of the API, but I have removed the b'...' part that seems to be imported into the table.

```
clean_json = []
for i in rawJson:
    temp = i[2:-1]
    clean_json.append(temp)
```

And it does indeed only remove the b'..." part as you can see here:

```
print(clean_json[0])
{
   "itemId":43090845,
   "parentItemId":43090845,
   "name":"Better Homes and Gardens Owl Memory Foam Bath Rug, 20\\"   x     30\\"",
   "msrp":15.88,
   "salePrice":14.88,
   "upc":"040773068722",
   "categoryPath":"Home/Bath/Bath Rugs & Mats",
   "shortDescription":"Pamper your feet with this Memory Foam bath mat     from Mohawk Home. All synthetic textiles enable it to stand up to moisture.     Slip-resistant backing makes it extra safe and fast drying. Bath rug is     machine washable.",
   "longDescription":"&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Better Homes and Gardens Owl     Memory Foam Bath Rug, 20&quot; x     30&quot;:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Machine     washable&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Slip-resistant backing&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Fast     drying&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Soft to touch&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Material     Content: Polyester&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Better Homes and Garden bath rugs is     extra safe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;",
   "brandName":"Better Homes & Gardens",
   "thumbnailImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
   "mediumImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
   "largeImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
   "productTrackingUrl":"http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-    bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&    tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.walmart.com%252Fip%252FBetter-    Homes-and-Gardens-Owl-Memory-Foam-Bath-Rug-20-    x-30%252F43090845%253Faffp1%253D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
   "ninetySevenCentShipping":false,
   "standardShipRate":5.99,
   "size":"20\\"   x 30\\"",
   "color":"Brown",
   "marketplace":false,
   "shipToStore":true,
   "freeShipToStore":true,
   "modelNumber":"BH15-005-599-01",
   "productUrl":"http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=https%3A%2F    %2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FBetter-Homes-and-Gardens-Owl-Memory-Foam-Bath-    Rug-20-x-30%2F43090845%3Faffp1%3D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlya    pi",
   "customerRating":"4.4",
   "numReviews":5,
   "customerRatingImage":"http://i2.walmartimages.com/i/CustRating    /4_4.gif",
   "categoryNode":"4044_539095_920259",
   "rhid":"30609",
   "bundle":false,
   "clearance":false,
   "preOrder":false,
   "stock":"NOT_AVAILABLE",
   "attributes":{
      "color":"Brown",
      "ironBankCategory":"Home Decor",
      "size":"20\\"      x 30\\""
   },
   "gender":"Unisex",
   "addToCartUrl":"http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=http%3A%2F    %2Faffil.walmart.com%2Fcart%2FaddToCart%3Fitems%3D43090845%7C1%26affp1%3D3NMs    qL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlya    pi",
   "affiliateAddToCartUrl":"http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-    bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&    tmpid=1082&    RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Faffil.walmart.com%252Fcart%252FaddToCart%253Fitem    s%253D43090845%257C1%2526affp1%253D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%2526affilsrc%253Dapi",
   "freeShippingOver35Dollars":true,
   "imageEntities":[
      {
         "thumbnailImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "mediumImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "largeImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "entityType":"SECONDARY"
      },
      {
         "thumbnailImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "mediumImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "largeImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "entityType":"SECONDARY"
      },
      {
         "thumbnailImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/56639088-94cb-46b3-8a3c-    750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=100&        odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "mediumImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "largeImage":"https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF",
         "entityType":"PRIMARY"
      }
   ],
   "availableOnline":false
}
```

I try to parse this string using the loads function in the json module using the string as a raw input:

```
parsed_json = []
for i in clean_json:
    temp = json.loads(r"""i""")
    parsed_json.append(temp)
```

However I keep getting this error :

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

This error is super vague and I am not sure what letter "s" it's looking for. I have tried ijson from GitHub with no luck. How should I parse this json?

Comment: What are you expecting `"""i"""` to do exactly?

Comment: Its the r"""...""" format for raw string input suggested to me by a friend who thought perhaps some characters in the document were being interpreted incorrectly by the parser.

Comment: My hint didn't seem to help so I've added an explicit answer (`r"""i"""` is just the string `"i"`, **not the variable `i`**)

Comment: Thanks. I know it is the string, that's what I am trying to pass through the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting from the API is not a string, but an encoded set of bytes. Instead of using your hack to convert this to a string, use the actual Python method `decode()` (which will use the default encoding if not argument is given):

```
json_string = raw_json[0].decode()
```

Now you have an actual string to pass to `json.loads`:

```
data = json.loads(json_string)
```

With your data, I can pretty print it using the pprint module as:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Giving:

```
{'addToCartUrl': 'http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=http%3A%2F    '
                 '%2Faffil.walmart.com%2Fcart%2FaddToCart%3Fitems%3D43090845%7C1%26affp1%3D3NMs    '
                 'qL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    '
                 'L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlya    '
                 'pi',
 'affiliateAddToCartUrl': 'http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-    '
                          'bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&    '
                          'tmpid=1082&    '
                          'RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Faffil.walmart.com%252Fcart%252FaddToCart%253Fitem    '
                          's%253D43090845%257C1%2526affp1%253D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    '
                          'L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%2526affilsrc%253Dapi',
 'attributes': {'color': 'Brown',
                'ironBankCategory': 'Home Decor',
                'size': '20"      x 30"'},
 'availableOnline': False,
 'brandName': 'Better Homes & Gardens',
 'bundle': False,
 'categoryNode': '4044_539095_920259',
 'categoryPath': 'Home/Bath/Bath Rugs & Mats',
 'clearance': False,
 'color': 'Brown',
 'customerRating': '4.4',
 'customerRatingImage': 'http://i2.walmartimages.com/i/CustRating    /4_4.gif',
 'freeShipToStore': True,
 'freeShippingOver35Dollars': True,
 'gender': 'Unisex',
 'imageEntities': [{'entityType': 'SECONDARY',
                    'largeImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    '
                                  'd71a-4dd4-8cbb-    '
                                  'afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    '
                                  'odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF',
                    'mediumImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    '
                                   'd71a-4dd4-8cbb-    '
                                   'afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    '
                                   'odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF',
                    'thumbnailImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    '
                                      'd71a-4dd4-8cbb-    '
                                      'afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    '
                                      'odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF'},
                   {'entityType': 'SECONDARY',
                    'largeImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com    '
                                  '/asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    '
                                  'bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    '
                                  'odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF',
                    'mediumImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com    '
                                   '/asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    '
                                   'bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    '
                                   'odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF',
                    'thumbnailImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com    '
                                      '/asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    '
                                      'bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    '
                                      'odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF'},
                   {'entityType': 'PRIMARY',
                    'largeImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    '
                                  '46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    '
                                  'odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF',
                    'mediumImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    '
                                   '46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    '
                                   'odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF',
                    'thumbnailImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com    '
                                      '/asr/56639088-94cb-46b3-8a3c-    '
                                      '750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=100&        '
                                      'odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF'}],
 'itemId': 43090845,
 'largeImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    '
               '46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    '
               'odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF',
 'longDescription': '&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Better Homes and Gardens Owl     '
                    'Memory Foam Bath Rug, 20&quot; x     '
                    '30&quot;:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Machine     '
                    'washable&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Slip-resistant '
                    'backing&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Fast     '
                    'drying&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Soft to '
                    'touch&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Material     Content: '
                    'Polyester&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Better Homes and Garden '
                    'bath rugs is     extra safe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;',
 'marketplace': False,
 'mediumImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    '
                '46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    '
                'odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF',
 'modelNumber': 'BH15-005-599-01',
 'msrp': 15.88,
 'name': 'Better Homes and Gardens Owl Memory Foam Bath Rug, 20"   x     30"',
 'ninetySevenCentShipping': False,
 'numReviews': 5,
 'parentItemId': 43090845,
 'preOrder': False,
 'productTrackingUrl': 'http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-    '
                       'bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&    '
                       'tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.walmart.com%252Fip%252FBetter-    '
                       'Homes-and-Gardens-Owl-Memory-Foam-Bath-Rug-20-    '
                       'x-30%252F43090845%253Faffp1%253D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    '
                       'L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%2526affilsrc%253Dapi',
 'productUrl': 'http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=https%3A%2F    '
               '%2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FBetter-Homes-and-Gardens-Owl-Memory-Foam-Bath-    '
               'Rug-20-x-30%2F43090845%3Faffp1%3D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    '
               'L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlya    '
               'pi',
 'rhid': '30609',
 'salePrice': 14.88,
 'shipToStore': True,
 'shortDescription': 'Pamper your feet with this Memory Foam bath mat     from '
                     'Mohawk Home. All synthetic textiles enable it to stand '
                     'up to moisture.     Slip-resistant backing makes it '
                     'extra safe and fast drying. Bath rug is     machine '
                     'washable.',
 'size': '20"   x 30"',
 'standardShipRate': 5.99,
 'stock': 'NOT_AVAILABLE',
 'thumbnailImage': 'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    '
                   '46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    '
                   'odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF',
 'upc': '040773068722'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the line that has

```
"20\\"     x30\\"",
```

in it as far as I can tell. Clean that line up and see if it works.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do this without actually removing the information? I might need it later

Comment: Not really as I don't know what's supposed to be there. I assume "20x30"? But that field is formatted in some weird way. Maybe the simplest, fastest way is to replace any back characters/string with empty data -- like replace the \\" character string with nothing and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `json.loads(r"""i""")` is attempting to decode `"i"` ... which is meaningless.  Perhaps you meant to interpolate the variable `i` as `"""{}""".format(i)` ... but then why not just use `json.loads(i)` in that case.

```
>>> json.loads(raw_json[0][2:-1])
{u'marketplace': False, u'preOrder': False, u'color': u'Brown', u'imageEntities': [{u'entityType': u'SECONDARY', u'thumbnailImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'largeImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'mediumImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2a6072b1-    d71a-4dd4-8cbb-    afb358bc04d2_1.e766841c15741606236fb13fec3aa347.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF'}, {u'entityType': u'SECONDARY', u'thumbnailImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'largeImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'mediumImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/d1dbd2e0-8bd1-4e12-ac2b-    bfa24cb6e980_1.1083a714bcf34400fdab2b1dc19df4a3.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF'}, {u'entityType': u'PRIMARY', u'thumbnailImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com    /asr/56639088-94cb-46b3-8a3c-    750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=100&        odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'largeImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'mediumImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF'}], u'numReviews': 5, u'productUrl': u'http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=https%3A%2F    %2Fwww.walmart.com%2Fip%2FBetter-Homes-and-Gardens-Owl-Memory-Foam-Bath-    Rug-20-x-30%2F43090845%3Faffp1%3D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlya    pi', u'ninetySevenCentShipping': False, u'customerRatingImage': u'http://i2.walmartimages.com/i/CustRating    /4_4.gif', u'rhid': u'30609', u'addToCartUrl': u'http://c.affil.walmart.com/t/api01?l=http%3A%2F    %2Faffil.walmart.com%2Fcart%2FaddToCart%3Fitems%3D43090845%7C1%26affp1%3D3NMs    qL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%26affilsrc%3Dapi%26veh%3Daff%26wmlspartner%3Dreadonlya    pi', u'shortDescription': u'Pamper your feet with this Memory Foam bath mat     from Mohawk Home. All synthetic textiles enable it to stand up to moisture.     Slip-resistant backing makes it extra safe and fast drying. Bath rug is     machine washable.', u'freeShipToStore': True, u'size': u'20"   x 30"', u'customerRating': u'4.4', u'brandName': u'Better Homes & Gardens', u'mediumImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=180&    odnWidth=180&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'productTrackingUrl': u'http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-    bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&    tmpid=1082&RD_PARM1=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.walmart.com%252Fip%252FBetter-    Homes-and-Gardens-Owl-Memory-Foam-Bath-Rug-20-    x-30%252F43090845%253Faffp1%253D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%2526affilsrc%253Dapi', u'stock': u'NOT_AVAILABLE', u'categoryNode': u'4044_539095_920259', u'largeImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=450&    odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'parentItemId': 43090845, u'thumbnailImage': u'https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/56639088-94cb-    46b3-8a3c-750633ade144_1.74c9173baaca23617a1086156ee5f976.jpeg?odnHeight=100&    odnWidth=100&odnBg=FFFFFF', u'bundle': False, u'longDescription': u'&lt;br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Better Homes and Gardens Owl
 Memory Foam Bath Rug, 20&quot; x     30&quot;:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Machine     washable&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Slip-resistant backing&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Fast     drying&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Soft to touch&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Material     Content: Polyester&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Better Homes and Garden bath rugs is     extra safe&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;', u'standardShipRate': 5.99, u'categoryPath': u'Home/Bath/Bath Rugs & Mats', u'shipToStore': True, u'freeShippingOver35Dollars': True, u'itemId': 43090845, u'availableOnline': False, u'name': u'Better Homes and Gardens Owl Memory Foam Bath Rug, 20"   x     30"', u'gender': u'Unisex', u'upc': u'040773068722', u'modelNumber': u'BH15-005-599-01', u'salePrice': 14.88, u'affiliateAddToCartUrl': u'http://linksynergy.walmart.com/fs-    bin/click?id=|LSNID|&offerid=223073.7200&type=14&catid=8&subid=0&hid=7200&    tmpid=1082&    RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Faffil.walmart.com%252Fcart%252FaddToCart%253Fitem    s%253D43090845%257C1%2526affp1%253D3NMsqL2_UxcE1HIonNkB-    L5B02IQEPQWawum0w3ENkc%2526affilsrc%253Dapi', u'attributes': {u'color': u'Brown', u'ironBankCategory': u'Home Decor', u'size': u'20"      x 30"'}, u'clearance': False, u'msrp': 15.88}
```

Comment: When I do this as json.loads(i) I get this error :


    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter